# Trying to get text in square to transform together

Tags: graphics

I use

```
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], LightGray, Rectangle[], {Black, Text[Style[F, FontSize -> 442, Bold, FontFamily -> Arial], {1/2, 1/2}]}}]
```

to put an "F" in a square. When I rotate,

```
    Graphics[GeometricTransformation[{EdgeForm[Thick], LightGray, Rectangle[], {Black,Text[Style[F, FontSize -> 442, Bold, FontFamily -> Arial], {1/2, 1/2}]}}, RotationTransform[30 Degree]], Frame -> True]
```

The "F" is now bigger than the square. I read previous questions/answers, but the best,

```
/. Graphics -> Identity // Graphics
```

Fixes 180 degrees, but not others.
Thanks

Comment: I want to help, but I can't use the F word. I have some reputation to keep.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different approach. First I create an image of the word.

```
text = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], LightGray, 
    Rectangle[], {Black, Text[Style["Q", FontSize -> 442, Bold, 
    FontFamily -> "Arial"], {1/2, 1/2}]}}];
```

[image]

Then I place it on the square

```
Graphics[{Texture[text], 
  Polygon[RotationTransform[30 Degree][{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

One advantage here is that you can use any polygon. For example

```
Graphics[{Texture[text], 
  Polygon[RotationTransform[0 Degree][{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
fig = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], LightGray, 
   Rectangle[], {Black, 
    Text[Style[F, FontSize -> 442, Bold, FontFamily -> Arial], {1/2, 
      1/2}]}}]
Rotate[fig, 40Degree]
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Add the option `ImageSize` using the form `ImageSize -> 1 - size` (with  *large enough* `size`):

```
Row[{Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Thick], LightGray, Rectangle[]}, {Black, 
     Text[Style[F, FontSize -> 442, Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial"], {1/2, 1/2}]}}, 
    Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 1 -> 350], 
  Graphics[GeometricTransformation[{{EdgeForm[Thick], LightGray, Rectangle[]},
     {Black, Text[Style[F, FontSize -> 442, Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial"], {1/2, 1/2}]}}, 
    RotationTransform[30 Degree]],
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 1 -> 350]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

**2.** Transform text primitives to `FilledCurve`s use them as `Inset`:

```
text = Graphics @ ImportString[ExportString[
      Style["F", Italic, FontSize -> 442, Bold, 
       FontFamily -> "Arial"], "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"][[1, 1]];

Row[{Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], LightGray, 
    Rectangle[], {Black, Inset[text, {1/2, 1/2}]}},
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200],
  Graphics[GeometricTransformation[{EdgeForm[Thick], LightGray, 
     Rectangle[], {Black, Inset[text, {1/2, 1/2}]}}, 
     RotationTransform[30 Degree]], 
  Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]